# About Spring Boot encrypt/decrypt functions

Tags: encryption, java

I'm looking for some advice about Spring boot CLI command [encrypt/decrypt](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_security):

I understand that Java Cryptography Extension is required for those functions.
They provide symmetric encryption.

Does anyone know what kind of algorithm is used?
Is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that it relies on Spring's default Encryptors, which according to the [official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/crypto.html) would be 256-bit AES with PBKDF2.